# Test GWT SimplePager ImageButton enabled state in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gwt

We are using the GWT provided `SimplePager` to provide record/page navigation through data sets.  We want to test that we are controlling the enabled state of the Next/Previous buttons properly.  While SimplePager lets us specify enabled/disabled images for the buttons, the "button" itself is an internal class of `ImageButton` which extends `Image` rather than Button.  Therefore the resulting HTML does not use Button enabled/disabled attributes, but rather provides a different embedded image for each state.

Is there any reasonable way to detect the SimplePager navigation button enabled states in Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

In standard practice you should create custom component, let say Image button. I would suggest you to use [ISFW](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp#testing-frameworks) which provides feature of [creating custom component](http://blog.infostretch.com/isfw-faq#_How_can_I_1) that can be used with annotation. In component you can specify behavior in as per AUT.

Comment: I think you may have missed the point of my question.  I want to use the SimplePager rather than reinvent a parallel and almost duplicate implementation.  I was hoping that there was some strategy for detecting the enabled/disabled state of the sub-component ImageButton that is used internally to SimplePager.

Comment: If i understand properly then following custom component can satisfy requirement

Comment: public class ImageButton extends Component{
 public ImageButtom (String loc){
 super(locator);
 } 

 @Override
 public boolean isEnabled() {
 //custom representation!.
 return getAttribute("class").contains("imgdisabled");
 //return getCssValue("background").contains("imgdisabled");
 //return getAttribute("src").contains("imgdisabled");
 }
}

You can use this component instead of Webelement in your test page
@FindBy(locator="locator")
ImageButton prevButton;

@FindBy(locator="locator")
ImageButton nextButton;

In your test code
page.prevButton.verifyEnabled();
page.prevButton.assertEnabled();

Answer (score 0):

Re-writing the code sample to have better formatting.

```
public class ImageButton extends Component{
   public ImageButtom (String loc){
    super(locator);
   } 

   @Override
   public boolean isEnabled() {
    //custom representation!...
    return this.getAttribute("class").contains("imgdisabled");
    //return this.getCssValue("background").contains("imgdisabled");
    //return this.getAttribute("src").contains("imgdisabled");
   }
}
```

You can use this component like Webelement in your test page

```
@FindBy(locator="locator")
ImageButton prevButton;

@FindBy(locator="locator")
ImageButton nextButton;
```

In your test code

```
page.prevButton.verifyEnabled();
page.prevButton.assertEnabled();
```

Comment: Once again, I am not looking for something new that acts like GWT's `ImageButton`, but rather I am looking for a way to test GWT's `SimplePager`, which *internally* uses an `ImageButton` for the navigation buttons.  If I were to follow your advice, I would have to not only redefine ImageButton, but also all of SimplePager.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of SimplePager, it looks like they use a generator to create the css styles, where the disabled state (and the enabled state) has a css class applied to it (i m going off this https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/SimplePager.java?r=9614).

So if you can somehow get access to the actual `Resources` client bundle, then you can call `resources.simplePagerStyle().disabledButton()` to get a string that is the css class for the disabled button, and you can then use that as a locator in selenium. That might be really tricky tho, because the jvm running your selenium test may not be able to reference the compiled GWT code (i.e., the code that runs when you debug a GWT app).

Alternatively, you can subclass `SimplePager`, instead of using the `DEFAULT_RESOURCES` client bundle, pass in your own, and then you get to control the classname used for the disabled button (by making your own `Style` class, which just wraps the existing one you get from the original client bundle, but add a prefix or something to the return value).

It's a bit messy, because the component is quite encapsulated, and you are trying to get at its innards.